# Conversion error when copying from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I'm getting an error when trying to use the Attunity connector (Oracle source) to consume an Oracle table to later send to a SQL Server table.

> Error: 0x27B at PROJECT_COST_HISTORY oracleSource 1, Oracle Source [331]: A conversion error occurred. Column name is 'PERIOD_NAME'.
>
> Error: 0xC0047038 at PROJECT_COST_HISTORY oracleSource 1, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on Oracle Source returned error code 0x80004005. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

BUT, the big problem I'm seeing is that apparently the issue is not with the marked `PERIOD_NAME` column, as if I remove all other columns other than this one then the process works and perform the inserts.

From the Oracle source, I'm retrieving about 60 columns with different data types, then I'm doing a conversion and converting to:

- database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2]
- double precision
- float [DT_R8]
- numeric [DT_NUMERIC]
- unicode string [DT_WSTR]

If I remove the conversion and OLEDB Destination and deploy to SQL Server, the package does run successfully, which gives me the idea that the reading part does work properly.

However when I do have the conversion and OLEDB Dest. I get the error stating "conversion error" as stated before.

Just to add info, the `PERIOD_NAME` column in Oracle has data such as

```
MAY-FY2021
NOV-FY2018
APR-FY2017
SEP-FY2019
```

and I double checked all for anything strange.

Is there other way I could try to debug this error? I was also able to do the copying from Oracle to SQL Server without SSIS with a console app in C#, however this process is quite slow this way (with `SqlBulkCopy` and a data reader).

Also, if it worth mentioning, the table structure in SQL Server was created by doing a

```
select * 
into TABLE 
from openquery('alias', 'select * from table where rownum < 2')
```

to get the initial structure.

Comment: Suggest you be more explicit about what the source type is.  In SQL, you can store those values in a string column, so perhaps you can change the SQL Server column type to get this to avoid the conversion error.

Comment: I've changed the conversion for all of them to go to VARCHARN, and I still get the same conversion error, I have also changed all destination columns to VARCHARN.
with regards of the source, I don't have access to see table definition in oracle, is that what you mean?

Comment: this is giving error directly from reading from oracle. not even getting to a conversion

Comment: After your select * into table from your post, please go look at sys.columns and see what column types are created for each column.  You may need to create a separate table table2 where all the columns are strings instead to get things to move.  Oracle and SQL's type systems are somewhat different and dates and other types may not convert perfectly through OLEDB and linked servers without modification.

Comment: I have created a version of it in sql server where all the destination tables are string, however, it seems that the issue is when reading from oracle, as if I remove the destination to sql server, or replace with a flat file, still gives the conversion error, the "conversion error" appear on the oracle source element

Comment: oh, I stand corrected, the issue comes when sending to a destination in the server, If I have an oracle source and a data conversion element alone it works, when I add the table at the destination it fails with the conversion

Comment: it's weird because the one that fails according to sql server catalog is the "oracle source" subcomponent, but it does work if I remove the oledb destination

Comment: You could try a linked server to the provider or to the native Oracle provider, perhaps, but I'm out of ideas otherwise

Comment: with a linked server it works, and with an OLEDB source it also works, the thing is that I was trying to use the Attunity connectors as it is faster, right now I'm running it with OLEDB Source :(